# Get Holidays List of Australia from Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api

I am using

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=YourApiKey

to get australian public holidays, but I am receiving empty items array

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p32kslj59m6eeu0g\"",
 "summary": "Holidays in Australia",
 "updated": "2021-03-05T08:30:05.375Z",
 "timeZone": "UTC",
 "accessRole": "reader",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextPageToken": "CjASLgojMjAyMTA0MDVfNjBvMzBjaGk2b28zMGMxZzYwbzMwZHI1NmsYkN324_Pw7gIaDwgAEgAYmKz8oN6Y7wIgASIHCAIQzunfEQ==",
 "items": []
}
```

any idea how to get australian holidays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Calendar API is returning the correct results, but it is returning them across several pages. You can get the next page with:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=YourApiKey&pageToken=CjASLgojMjAyMTA0MDVfNjBvMzBjaGk2b28zMGMxZzYwbzMwZHI1NmsYkN324_Pw7gIaDwgAEgAYmKz8oN6Y7wIgASIHCAIQzunfEQ==

See more about pagination here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/pagination
The client libraries make it easy to deal with these multi-paged responses.

The page size defaults to 250 events, but this also includes deleted events, which you are not requesting. The first 250 events on this particular calendar have been marked as deleted, so you see an empty page.

See details at: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

> maxResults (integer)
> Maximum number of events returned on one result page. **The number of events in the resulting page may be less than this value, or none at all, even if there are more events matching the query**. Incomplete pages can be detected by a non-empty nextPageToken field in the response. By default the value is 250 events. The page size can never be larger than 2500 events. Optional.

I was able to force everything onto a single page using the following, but this really isn't a good answer. If total event count is larger than 2500, you still might end up with an incomplete list:
[https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?maxResults=2500&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]'](https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?maxResults=2500&key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D%27)

Comment: So you dont think there is an issue that the initial call returns 0 results forcing you to use a next page token?  This is a bug the first call should return the first X number of results then if there are more results then and only then should you need to use the next page token.   While your answer may have some valid information you statement that the API is returning the correct results is incorrect.

Comment: I can only go by what the API docs say, which clearly state that a blank page is normal behavior (I agree this isn't a very good UX).  The root cause seems to be that there are 654 cancelled events on this calendar. They're filtered out of the request if you don't ask for them with showDeleted=True, but pagination of the response doesn't change. Specific to holiday calendars, the presence of cancelled events may be worth raising as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error in that the initial response returns no events however there is a page token  This is not how the system is intended to function. I have submitted an [issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182024836)

[try me](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com%22%7D)

Request;

curl \

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Returns

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p33kpjmcjvaeuu0g\"",
 "summary": "Holidays in Australia",
 "updated": "2021-03-06T07:14:02.000Z",
 "timeZone": "UTC",
 "accessRole": "reader",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextPageToken": "CjASLgojMjAyMTA0MDVfNjBvMzBjaGk2b28zMGMxZzYwbzMwZHI1NmsYkN324_Pw7gIaDwgAEgAYgMXbj4-b7wIgASIHCAIQ5I7jEQ==",
 "items": []
}
```

Where it should return events

If i then add the next pagetoken

Request

curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?pageToken=CjASLgojMjAyMTA0MDVfNjBvMzBjaGk2b28zMGMxZzYwbzMwZHI1NmsYkN324_Pw7gIaDwgAEgAYgMXbj4-b7wIgASIHCAIQ5I7jEQ%3D%3D&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--compressed

## response

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p32e9tk5uvaeuu0g\"",
 "summary": "Holidays in Australia",
 "updated": "2021-03-06T07:14:02.000Z",
 "timeZone": "UTC",
 "accessRole": "reader",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextPageToken": "CjASLgojMjAyMjEyMjZfNjBvMzBjaGk2NG8zNGMxZzYwbzMwZHI1Nm8YsM-liJbz7gIaDwgAEgAYgMXbj4-b7wIgASIHCAIQvo_jEQ==",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3227284619238000\"",
   "id": "20200425_60o30chi6so3gc1g60o30dr56g",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAyMDA0MjVfNjBvMzBjaGk2c28zZ2MxZzYwbzMwZHI1NmcgZW4uYXVzdHJhbGlhbiNob2xpZGF5QHY",
   "created": "2021-02-18T09:58:29.000Z",
   "updated": "2021-02-18T09:58:29.619Z",
   "summary": "ANZAC Day Observed (Victoria)",
   "description": "Holiday or observance in: Victoria",
```

The response is returned corectly.